# Single value from cursor to int

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't seem to figure out how I get the result from my select query (which should be one number) into my int min. Found different solution using Google but none worked.

I need the min value in order to check if the score that the current player has is higher than the lowest score in order to get in the highscores.

```
public int getMin(){
        System.out.println("in getmin");
        String selectQuery = "SELECT MIN(score) FROM tblscore;";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int min = "something here to put the result in the int"
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return min;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the value through a cursor, but for single-valued queries like this, there is helper function in the [DatabaseUtils class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) which makes things simpler:

```java
public int getMin(){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT MIN(score) FROM tblscore";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        return (int)DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, selectQuery, null);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for being informative! Didn't know about this class.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to point the cursor to the first line:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Then you can use [`Cursor.getInt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29) to get the value:

```
int min = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Comment: At this moment, the cursor does not have a current row.